# How to include ODBC ver 3.0 libraries in my MFC app in Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, odbc, using

1. I created my own ODBC wrapper class which handles SQL from C++ Win32 application.
2. I have copied and Added (as existing) this class to my MFC application.

Now I have terrible linking problems with unresolved external symbols (which were NOT present in the Win32 perfectly working app), such as this: "

Error   56
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SQLSetStmtAttr@16 referenced in function 
"public: int __thiscall Cosql::ODBCconnect(char *)" (?ODBCconnect@Cosql@@QAEHPAD@Z)

C:\Documents and Settings.........\Cosql.obj   ApplicationName
"

How can I PROPERLY include "sqlext.h" (and "sql.h") from
   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A          in my MFC application or MORE importantly:  How to resolve those external symbols?

Am I the only one trying to ODBC-connect from a MFC app  and having this trouble ??? :O

I Just know that "SQLSetStmtAttr" function is there defined only for ODBCVER 3.0 and higher. Well ! But HOW do I set ODBCVER in my MFC app. ??? I have no idea.

EDIT: I figured out that ODBCVER is defined: 0x0380 (so it is ver. 3.8),
all functions are defined correctly by those includes: sql.h and sqlext.h  ,

EDIT II:  Linking ERROR persists when I convert all those methods (object) into pure functions using some global variables!

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**

Solution: I created a DLL from my ODBC class and then used it in my project.
Now it is compiled independently so it does not restrict each other's INCOMPATIBLE environment and compiler settings anymore!